# How to start with mobile testing with Appium

Tags: selenium, appium

Can anyone suggest to startup way with Appium mobile testing. Already have knowledge of Automation testing using Selenium.

Comment: help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start with android automation as you automate basically any app. Use your phone if you have android and if not install genny motion as virtual machine

try this
https://www.guru99.com/introduction-to-appium.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get started with Android automation which is easy to understand and resources & tutorials are easily available.

Refer : http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?java#

Also , if you are starting with Android first , get familiar with few basic Android commands - like ADB , AAPT .
Learn how to obtain package name of any application. UDID of Android device etc.

try this to get package name /udid of android phone - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEUDm1ZxsX6teks8wM71bmQ/videos
&
https://qahumor.blogspot.in/2015/06/

Hope these are helpful to get start with basic things.